# Unable to fix cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to remove this error but I'm unable to sort this issue, It's pretty obvious when there's no data to filter that happens and I want to avoid it

I have a function to filter out the data

```
const filteredItems = useMemo(() => {
    return results.filter((quote) => {
      const a = quote.customer_reference.toLowerCase().includes(customer_reference.toLowerCase())
      const b = quote.created_by.toLowerCase().includes(created_by.toLowerCase())
      const c = quote.quote_status.toLowerCase().includes(quote_status.toLowerCase())

      if (a && b && c) {
        return true
      }

      return false
    })
  })
```

Here `results` is a list of items from backed, and it takes a little time to load the data from the backend until then it crashes and gives that undefined error. And also I need the filtered list to pass into the data table, like here.

```
    <DataTable
      noHeader
      size="sm"
      pagination
      columns={advSearchColumns}
      paginationPerPage={7}
      className="table-sm"
      sortIcon={<ChevronDown size={10} />}
      paginationDefaultPage={currentPage + 1}
      paginationComponent={CustomPagination}
      data={filteredItems} // Thats the filtered items 
    />
```

Full error
×

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')
```

Comment: And where specifically is something trying to read a property of `undefined`?  Which variable is `undefined` and what value do you expect that variable to have?

Comment: At this line return results.filter((quote) => {

Comment: I would recommend using `results?.filter(` for better error handling.  Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on a comment above, indicating that the error is thrown here:

```
return results.filter((quote) => {
```

If `results` is undefined then you can't "filter" anything on it.  What should `filteredItems` return in that case?  For example, you can perform null checking to return null:

```
return results?.filter((quote) => {
```

Or perhaps you could conditionally return an empty array:

```
return results ? results.filter((quote) => {
  //...
}) : [];
```

Comment: you could also do `return results?.filter(() => {} ) ?? []`

Comment: That was pretty easy I was trying to wrap the whole function in if statement , Thanks btw it is working